# Obtaining and Parsing Map Street Data in Python

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, planning, openstreetmap

How would you obtain a graph describing street interconnections and estimated driving times, and parse it using Python?

As an exercise, I'm trying to implement a basic A* planner to plot a route for navigating between two points on a map (i.e. TomTom, Garmin, Google Nav, etc). I could mock up some data, but I'd like to use real map data if possible.

I'm aware of [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org), and while they allow exporting of small slices of their map into OSM XML data, I'm having trouble finding tools to easily parse this a form I can use. I've found [imposm](http://dev.omniscale.net/imposm.parser/), but not much else. Can anyone recommend any other tools?

Comment: I wouldn't try to do it in python - I'd get my data into PostGIS and use the pgrouting module. Also there are similar questions on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Spacedman, I agree, PostGIS+pgrouting is the "proper" way to go if my end-goal is trip planning. But that's not really my end-goal. I want to parse it with Python as an exercise with building an A* based planner.